# Axios auto refresh every 60 seconds with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm using ReactJS as a javascript library and I am getting the data in `componentDidMount()` using `axios`. These received data must be taken again every 60 seconds. What is the most efficient and good way to do this?

```
componentDidMount() {
  const newGteeChartSeries = [];
  const newGteeChartCategories = [];
  const newmultiSelectOption = [];

  axios.get(`http://www.xxxxxxx:xxxx/api/groupdata`).then(res => {
    this.state.gteeChartSeries.map(() => {
      const data = [];

      res.data.map((item, index) => {
        data.push(item.gtee);
        newGteeChartCategories.push(item.isyeri);
        newmultiSelectOption.push({ id: item.id, isyeri: item.isyeri });
      });
      newGteeChartSeries.push({ name: "GTEE", data });
    });

    this.setState({
      teeTableData: res.data,
      gteeChartSeries: newGteeChartSeries,
      multiSelectOptions: newmultiSelectOption,
      gteeChartoptions: {
        ...this.state.options,
        xaxis: {
          categories: newGteeChartCategories
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of going about it is to move the data fetching logic to a separate method and create an interval that will invoke this method every 60 seconds.

Make sure you store the number returned from `setInterval` on the component instance so you can use `clearInterval` in `componentWillUnmount`.

**Example**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  interval = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getData, 60000);
    this.getData();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  getData = () => {
    const newGteeChartSeries = [];
    const newGteeChartCategories = [];
    const newmultiSelectOption = [];

    axios.get(`http://www.xxxxxxx:xxxx/api/groupdata`).then(res => {
      this.state.gteeChartSeries.forEach(() => {
        const data = [];

        res.data.forEach((item, index) => {
          data.push(item.gtee);
          newGteeChartCategories.push(item.isyeri);
          newmultiSelectOption.push({ id: item.id, isyeri: item.isyeri });
        });
        newGteeChartSeries.push({ name: "GTEE", data });
      });

      this.setState({
        teeTableData: res.data,
        gteeChartSeries: newGteeChartSeries,
        multiSelectOptions: newmultiSelectOption,
        gteeChartoptions: {
          ...this.state.options,
          xaxis: {
            categories: newGteeChartCategories
          }
        }
      });
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap all in a function.
Call that function in `ComponentDidMount()`, and use `setInterval(myFunction(), 60000)` to call that function every 60 seconds

Below works without syntax error.Call that function without parenthesis

```
``componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval( this.props.Details, 6000);
    this.props.Details()
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }``
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest abstracting the api request into its own function

```
componentDidMount(){
 setInterval(yourApiCallFn(),60000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well let's do that with a normal javascript setTimeInterval.

```js
let intervalLoop = null; // a class variable
componentDidMount() {
  const newGteeChartSeries = [];
  const newGteeChartCategories = [];
  const newmultiSelectOption = [];
  
  this.intervalLoop = setInterval(()=>{
  axios.get(`http://www.xxxxxxx:xxxx/api/groupdata`).then(res => {
    this.state.gteeChartSeries.map(() => {
      const data = [];

      res.data.map((item, index) => {
        data.push(item.gtee);
        newGteeChartCategories.push(item.isyeri);
        newmultiSelectOption.push({
          id: item.id,
          isyeri: item.isyeri
        });
      });
      newGteeChartSeries.push({
        name: "GTEE",
        data
      });
    });

    this.setState({
      teeTableData: res.data,
      gteeChartSeries: newGteeChartSeries,
      multiSelectOptions: newmultiSelectOption,
      gteeChartoptions: {
        ...this.state.options,
        xaxis: {
          categories: newGteeChartCategories
        }
      }
    });
  });
  }, 60000);
}
// need to cleanup the timeinterval whenever we destroy the component
componentWillUnmount(){
clearInterval(this.intervalLoop)
}
```